# kotlinOptions.useIR = true causes error after upgrade to Kotlin 1.7.10

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I received a notification from android Studio to update my app to Kotlin 1.7.10. (all is working well at Kotlin 1.6.21)
When I did that, I started receiving an error for the line

```
kotlinOptions.useIR = true
```

(I previously put this in about a year ago when I removed

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

which I was told at the time was bad, and at the same time added in

```
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

)

The error I receive for the useIR line is:

```
> No such property: useIR for class: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptionsImpl
  Possible solutions: useK2
```

so I changed the line to:

```
    kotlinOptions.useK2 = true
```

...but a rebuild gives an error like this:

```
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
  e: kapt currently doesn't support experimental K2 compiler
  Disable K2 compiler by removing -Xuse-k2 flag
```

the only "K2" I have in my project is this line - but if I remove the line completely I get:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
  > A failure occurred while executing 
  org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
     > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

when I run with `--stacktrace` I see a couple of errors telling me to check my Kotlin version is >= 1.0 (!! my version is 1.7.10)

I should probably mention that I also see this warning:

```
We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32
```

Yet when I run the AGP Upgrade assistant, it doesn't show me a higher Gradle plugin to use than 7.2.1

Anyone have a clue what on earth is going on here?

Just to be clear - change Kotlin back to 1.6.21 fixes everything - so I'm not super stuck, but I want to understand how to go forward to newer versions of Kotlin

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use the option `useIR` with Kotlin 1.7 because it is enabled by default and cannot be disabled.
In fact, the property for enabling this option was deprecated previously and then removed completely in Kotlin 1.7: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compatibility-guide-17.html#remove-useir-compiler-option

Comment: OK, but just commenting the line out, I get execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'. as I wrote. So what should I do to fix that?

Comment: You should probably report the error with a full stack trace and preferably with a simple project to reproduce it to https://kotl.in/issue

Comment: done https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-53410/kotlinOptionsuseIR-true-causes-error-after-upgrade-to-Kotlin-1710